# Opening a Modal and sending URL to iFrame within

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to send a URL including some string data to the iframe named "galiframe". This is a basic image gallery so, within the link to the Modal I need to send stuff like the name of the image and it's physical address and a few more items to identify the user id, request #, mics... However, the jQuery link that opens the Modal does not allow me to do this. Any suggestion? P.S. I'm using classic .asp and jQuery css... Try not to laugh to hard... I'm old and so is my code.

```
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <style>
     body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

     /* The Modal */
     .modal {
       background-image: url("bgimg.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-color: #5DADE2;
       width: 80%;
       -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
       animation-name: animatetop;
       animation-duration: 0.4s
       border-radius: 10px;
       box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

     /* Add Animation */
     @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
     from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
     to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }

     @keyframes animatetop {
     from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
     to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }

    /* iframes Container */
    .frameset {
      display:inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      border: 0;
     }
   </style>
   <div id="ex1" class="modal">
      Image Gallery
      <div class="frameset">
        <iframe src="" name="galiframe"></iframe>
        <iframe src="listimg.asp" name="listframe"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--- Attach link from img to open the modal --->
    <!---Also sending URL to galliframe for img retrieval --->

    <a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">URL, Edit this image</a>
    <a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">URL, Edit a different image</a>
```

Comment: handle `show.bs.modal` event.

Comment: Not using bootstrap

Comment: what is the library that is used for showing the modal?

Comment: I added that information to the code above. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, hello, hello... Is there anybody out there? Just nod (ie.txt) if you can hear me... Is there anybody home?